# PHP как сохранить png-файл с черным фоном без образования лишних цветов?

Tags: php, png

Есть картинка с изображением разноцветных квадратов, передается в base64, декодируется: `$pngString = base64_decode($pngBase64);` При сохранении возле квадратов появляются пиксели с другими цветами, они не нужны.
Пробовала 2-мя вариантами, ни один не сработал как мне надо:

1. В этом варианте если выставлять белый фон - все ок, с черным тоже, но кроме основных цветов, по границам прямоугольников появляются промежуточные (к примеру если прямоугольник красный, то появляются бордовые пиксели)..

   ```
   $img = imagecreatefromstring($pngString);
   $black = imagecolorallocate($img, 0, 0, 0);
   imagefill($img, 0, 0, $black);
   imagepng($img, $outputFilePath);
   imagedestroy($img);
   ```
2. Наложением на новую картинку:

   ```
   $img = imagecreatefromstring($pngString);
   $w = imagesx($img);
   $h = imagesy($img);
   $img2 = imagecreatetruecolor($w, $h);
   imagefilledrectangle($img2, 0, 0, $w, $h, imagecolorallocate($img2, 0, 0, 0));
   imagecopyresampled($img2, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, $w, $h, $w, $h);
   imagepng($img2, $outputFilePath);
   imagedestroy($img);
   imagedestroy($img2);
   ```

Comment: [`imageantialias`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.imageantialias.php) не пробовали?

Comment: @teran попробовала - то же самое :(
https://labs.tineye.com/color/4cca1db9211518b906fad9b67565d2c079f9ebc5?ignore_background=True&color_format=hex&ignore_interior_background=True

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в `imagepng` 3-им параметром передать 0. Этот параметр значит степень сжатия - от 0 (нет сжатия) до 9. Подробнее можете прочитать в [документации imagepng](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.imagepng.php)